# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException while reading file

Tags: java, file-io

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Library.loadBooks(Library.java:179)
    at UseLibrary.main(UseLibrary.java:105)
```

This error makes me crazy!

```
public void loadBooks(String s) throws IOException{
    String str[] = new String[6];
    String inFName = ".//" + s ;
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inFName));
    int x;
    double y;
    String line = "";
    while(line != null){

        for(int i=0; i<6; i++){
            str[i] = new String();
            line = input.readLine();
            str = line.split("[-]");
            x = Integer.parseInt(str[1]);
            y = Double.parseDouble(str[2]);
            Book a = new Book(str[0], x, y, str[3], str[4], str[5]);
            add(a);
        } 

    }
}
```

What's the problem with this code?

I initialize the array, but it didn't run!

### Update 1

In `save.txt` I have is

```
1 Don Knuth-290-23.45-The Art of Programming with Java-HG456-Engineering-5 
2 A. Camp-400-13.45-An Open Life-HSA234-Philosophy-1 
3 James Jones-140-12.11-Oh, Java Yeah!-SDF213-Science Fiction-2 
4 J. Campbell-250-32.45-An Open Life-JH45-Science-3 
5 Mary Kennedy-230-56.32-Intro to CS Using Java as the Language-USN123-Science-4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The problem I think is

You have 5 or less lines in your `saved.txt` and because of for loop for the 6th iteration as there is no data for line, you are getting `NullPointerException`.

Please follow below step and let me know what you get...

### Instead of

```
while(line != null){

    for(int i=0; i<6; i++){
        str[i] = new String();
        line = input.readLine();
        str = line.split("[-]");
        x = Integer.parseInt(str[1]);
        y = Double.parseDouble(str[2]);
        Book a = new Book(str[0], x, y, str[3], str[4], str[5]);
        add(a);
    } 

}
```

### Use

```
while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
        str = line.split("[-]");
        Book a = new Book(str[0], Integer.parseInt(str[1]), Double.parseDouble(str[2]), str[3], str[4], str[5]);
        add(a);
}
```

Let me know if you still get any problem.

### Update 1

Per your update,

In `save.txt` I have is

```
1 Don Knuth-290-23.45-The Art of Programming with Java-HG456-Engineering-5 
2 A. Camp-400-13.45-An Open Life-HSA234-Philosophy-1 
3 James Jones-140-12.11-Oh, Java Yeah!-SDF213-Science Fiction-2 
4 J. Campbell-250-32.45-An Open Life-JH45-Science-3 
5 Mary Kennedy-230-56.32-Intro to CS Using Java as the Language-USN123-Science-4
```

As you see there are 5 lines in your file, for 6th iteration you are getting `NullPointerException`.

***Also read, [how to print content of files in Java](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080331201418AAzsIdJ).***

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand in which line Exception is thrown, but I guess that in these:

```
x = Integer.parseInt(str[1]);
y = Double.parseDouble(str[2]);
```

Before parsing check if `str[1]` and `str[2]` is not `null`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `while` loop that checks if `line` is null, it isn't so the while loop runs, but then you have a for loop that calls `line = input.readLine();`, 6 times, and never checks if that is null. At some point, `line` is probably null because you've reached the end of your file. You need to check if `line` is null inside your for loop or work out the looping differently.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in these two lines of code:

```
line = input.readLine();
str = line.split("[-]");
```

First, you read a line from a file. You assumed that the file has at least 6 lines, which is apparently a wrong assumption. [`BufferedReader#readLine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) returns `null` *if the end of the stream has been reached*. You don't check if `line` is null, and you call `split` on the null object which causes NPE.